# Shimano Hub automatically switches off while riding

Tags: dynamo

I have few Shimano dynamo Hubs and I had to face this issue on several: they seem to be on good working condition. I checked them on a truing stand with a light and they worked fine. Then when I start riding them, they light at low speed, then turned off automatically reaching few miles per hour. Finally, after few miles, they didn't even light at low speed.

Do you have any clue to help me fixing this issue ?

Comment: Is your truing stand made of aluminium and your bike fork of steel? can be an issue of improper connection?

Comment: How do you know it's the hub and not the light?

Comment: Additional questions, on the truing stand do you connect both lights? only the front light? the same front light you have on the bicycle?
When you stop going at some miles per hour, the light turns off, but when you start again does it stay off or does it light again? How long do you have to wait? If you have good lights with capacitors (that should stay on when stopped) there may be a connection problem (for example along the front-back wire), or an issue with the light internal electronics.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it made me think and put back my bike a stand and I found the issue: I use a 2nd hand switch for all my bikes and apparently this switch is working weirdly after some time. I set up the light without the switch and it worked fine. 
I still don't get how a switch can shortcut the electricity at 'high' speed, but for now I have light.